# Passing Q_DECLARE_METATYPE as a pointer

Tags: qt, qt5

This is my Container class.Which i declare in Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

```
class Container
  {
    private:
    std::string stdstrContainerName;
    std::string stdstrPluginType;
    Geometry Geom;

  public:
    Container();
    Container(std::string, std::string,  const Geometry& geometry );
    Container(const  Container& obj);
 };

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Container)
```

This class is a the data member in TreeItem.Since this is heavy object so i want to pass it as a pointer rather than a value.

```
class TreeItem
 {

    Container* data();

  private:
      QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
      Container itemData;
      TreeItem* parentItem;
  };

 Container* TreeItem::data()
 {
     return &itemData;
 }
```

I get compiler error that Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system

Comment: Is your `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` in a header file or an implementation file? Incidentally, there is a mistake in `TreeItem`. The default access for a `class` is `private`, so that `Container* data();` declares a `private` member function, but it looks like you expect it to be `public`.

Comment: Additionally, per https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, 1) You don't seem to have provided a public destructor, 2) Are you using the macro inside a namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a pointer you want to pass around, you need to tell MOC about that:

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Container*)`